# Power BI - How to get the previous 3 rows from any chosen row

Tags: powerbi, dax

this might be a bit confusing but on a Power BI table, I was wondering how would I get the previous 3 rows from any row? Basically, what I am trying to do is to mark 'yes' on the 'Past 3 recent from current' column based from the current date we are in. So if 'Current' is populated with Y, is there a way to populate the 3 previous row (dates) 'yes' on the last column? Would I have to create a calculated column or a measure? Please let me know if this is confusing. The image is the final outcome that I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: The three previous rows according to what? Power BI uses an algorithm to improve data compression and the order of the rows in the data model table may not be what you see if you create a visual that is sorted by date. Can you come up with a better logic than just the sort order? Is it the largest three date values that are smaller than the current date, maybe? But which date?

Comment: Hi @teylyn According to the current date, where 'Current' is marked as 'Y'. Yes, It would be based off either the end date or start date. The table is already sorted in order like this. I mean I can try adding an index column?

Comment: Please update your question with these details. Nobody wants to read through a wall of comments to find out what you're really after. Also, be more specific. Do you want to use start date or end date? You can't use both and "either" is not precise enough.

Comment: What is - current date? Is that today? or selected date from slicer?

Comment: @mkRabbani there no actual current date. I marked current as Y because the current date falls into the range between start and end date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, assuming that the `T[Start Date]` column has no duplicate values, like in your sample table, this calculated column could work. It first compute a variable `CurrentDate` with the `T[Start Date]` with `T[Current] = "Y"` and then it uses the `TOPN` function to get the top 3 `T[Start Date]` with less difference from the `CurrentDate`, using `FILTER` to remove dates greater or equal than `CurrentDate`

```
Past 3 recent from current =
VAR CurrentDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( T[Start Date] ),
        T[Current] = "Y",
        REMOVEFILTERS ( T )
    )
VAR PreviousStartDates =
    FILTER (
        VALUES ( T[Start Date] ),
        T[Start Date] < CurrentDate
    )
VAR Top3 =
    TOPN (
        3,
        PreviousStartDates,
        CurrentDate - T[Start Date], ASC
    )
VAR Result =
    IF (
        T[Start Date]
            IN Top3,
        "yes",
        "N"
    )
RETURN
    Result
```

The core of the code is the [`TOPN`](https://dax.guide/topn/) function, that retrieves the TOP 3 dates sorted by difference in days from the CurrentDate.

The first parameter is the number of rows to be returned, 3 in our case

The second parameter is the table to be sorted, that in our case is the variable `PreviousStartDates`, a table variable with a single column, `T[Start Date]`, filtered to remove the dates greater or equal to `CurrentDate`

The third parameter is the expression to be used to sort the table specified as second parameter. In our case it's the `CurrentDate - T[Start Date]`, the difference in days.

The fourth parameter, `ASC`, specifies the sorting order to go from the lowest days difference to the greatest.

Comment: Hi sergiom, thank you so much! Could you explain to me what each variable is doing in the Top3? I want to understand what is it doing.

Comment: HI, I removed the IF that was no more needed after the introduction of the FILTER. I moved the FILTER to an outer variable, to improve readability with a meaningful name, and I expanded the explanation adding the meaning of TOPN parameters. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: I also added a link to the dax guide about TOPN but it's not evident, I put it here also https://dax.guide/topn/

Comment: Thank you sergiom! That helps a lot!